# How to select time now() use sql query in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, datetime, sql-server-ce

I have connection to sdf file on visual studio 2010
But I can't select datetime now()
Image below
[image]
Can you help me?
thank

Answer (score 0):

`{ fn NOW() }` is ODBC syntax. Use `SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.